# Do I need Xammp for single php file to work?

Tags: php, forms, xampp

I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to PHP. I have a standard html/css/js project that I'm editing with VS code and running a development server with the Live Server extension, which is running on localhost:5500.

I'd like to integrate a single .php file into my project which will handle a form submission.

Will I need xampp running on my local machine in order for the .php file to work?

At the moment the form action is sending a post request to my .php file but I get a 405 error from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, A PHP processor is needed for the PHP code to work. If you have XAMPP installed (which means you have `php`), you can run

`php -S localhost:5501` (make sure `C:/xampp/php` is in your PATH environment variable)

in the root directory of your project, this will start a PHP server and you don't have to move everything to the `htdocs` folder.

Comment: Thanks! I'm on a Mac, so what would I need to do here instead in terms of the PATH environment variable? And what is the PATH environment variable? I've just successfully started the php server on 5501 in my project root folder but I'm still getting the 405 error

Comment: If the server was started that means `php` is already in the PATH. so no need to add.

405 just means that method is not allowed. Meaning if you're doing a `POST` method on the PHP script, it isn't allowed for some reason.

Comment: Try making the request to http://localhost:5501 this time because that's where PHP server is running.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked. I was still running the project on 5500 through Live Server so I think that's what was stopping it from working. I enter localhost:5501/index.html and then submitted the form and it worked. Final question if you don't mind me asking: when it comes to deploying the project to a live server, which can process php, I'm assuming it will handle all of this itself?

Comment: On the server, you'd have to install a proper server (nginx., apache). Which handles everything for you. There are great tutorials out there on how to install them as most servers are just linux servers.

Answer (score 2):

You need a server capable of processing PHP.

That doesn't need to be Apache HTTPD. If you do pick Apache HTTPD then you don't need to install it as part of XAMPP.

The Live Server extension is not capable of processing PHP so you need a different server. (I think I saw a PHP capable equivalent in the extensions library in VS Code, but I recall it being quite fiddly to configure.)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need a server (apache or nginx) + php.
Xampp include all this in one application: x (SO) A (apache) M(mysql) P(perl) P(php)